# Corregir espacios y mayusculas

Tags: python

Yo sigo con mi problema. Tengo que corregir un texto, primeros contar las palabras y todo eso, que eso lo tengo bien hecho (menos mal) pero ahora llega la parte de:
-mas de dos espacios no esta permitido, se puede tabular si se desea, pero dos espacios, no
-despues de . , , ;, : siempre un espacio
-despues de punto siempre espacio y mayusculas

Con mi codigo corrijo algo, pero no todo, y es mas, añado espacios.
A ver si podeis echarme un cable.

```
def correcciones(texto):
    texto = texto.replace('  ', '')
    texto = texto.replace('. ', '.')
    texto = texto.replace('.', '. ')
    texto = texto.replace(':', ': ')
    texto = texto.replace(';', '; ')
    texto = texto.replace(';  ', '; ')
    texto = texto.replace(',', ', ')
    texto = texto.replace('  ', '')
    texto = texto.replace('.    ', '.\t')
    texto = texto.replace(' -', ':\t-')
    texto = texto.replace('      ', '\t  ')
    return texto
```

Comment: En otra pregunta decías que no se te permite usar expresiones regulares. Es una pena porque simplifican la tarea. Sin ellas la implementación tendrá muchos "casos especiales" seguramente sin tratar bien. Por ejemplo el código que has puesto añade un espacio tras un punto, pero lo hace _siempre_, incluso si ya había uno, con lo que al final tendrías dos espacios tras el punto. Aunque luego reemplazas dos espacios por uno, con lo que eso se resolvería, a menos que hubiera tres espacios... etc ¿Es válido que queden esos casos "raros" sin tratar?

Comment: Lo de que tras un punto deba ir siempre mayúscula no es algo que puedas hacer con `replace()` y francamente no se me ocurre forma sencilla de hacerlo, sin mirar los caracteres uno a uno, o utilizar `.split()`, `.strip()` y otras cosas que quizás tampoco te estén permitidas.

Comment: ¿Tienes algún "banco de pruebas" con ejemplos de texto de entrada con los cuales se verificará que tu código lo hace bien?

Comment: Si, estoy trabajando con un texto mal escrito a drede pero, efectivamente, me planta un espacio detrás del punto, exista o no... split(), en un principio si está permitido, al menos no dice lo contrario.

Comment: Como te decía, replace no vale para todos los casos. Pero la alternativa es mucho más complicada... y no sé si es lo que tu profesor espera. Lo que se me ocurre es recorrer _letra a letra_ la cadena e implementar una especie de "máquina de estados" que vaya generando caracteres según lo que acaba de leer y el estado en que se halla. El carácter que encuentre también le haría cambiar de estado. No sé si entiendes de qué estoy hablando. Si no, será que no es esto lo que te piden, pero sin expresiones regulares y solo con replace tampoco creo que pueda hacerse...

Comment: Pues haciendo la cuenta de la vieja, he arreglado todo, me queda solo:
- despues de punto seguido poner mayusculas 
- y entre minúscula y mayusculas poner .
- y la porra del tabulador

Comment: @abulafia hecho

ah! tambien tengo que ver que si es un numero no me quite las comas o numeros, si por opciones que no falte

Comment: Esta última especificación no puede hacerse con `replace()`. Realmente, el tipo de opciones que te piden parecen diseñadas para obligarte a usar expresiones regulares, o bien una máquina de estados. Me resulta muy difícil ayudarte sin tener claro qué se supone que sabes o que puedes usar, y más si vas dando las especificaciones "con cuentagotas"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Espacios y tabs

Como bien dices, mediante "la cuenta de la vieja" y mucho cuidado, pueden ir completándose la mayoría de los casos a base de `replace()`.

Es crucial no obstante el orden en que aplicas los `replace()`, ya que si por ejemplo primero haces el que convierte dos espacios en uno, entonces una secuencia de cuatro espacios ya no será detectada como TAB, pues se habrá comprimido a una de solo dos.

Creo que la siguiente secuencia funcionará bien en la mayoría de casos. Sería interesante que proporcionaras el texto sobre el cual haces las pruebas, para comprobar que sale como se espera.

```
def correcciones(texto):
    texto = texto.replace('.', '. ')
    texto = texto.replace(':', ': ')
    texto = texto.replace(';', '; ')
    texto = texto.replace(',', ', ')
    texto = texto.replace('    ', '\t')
    texto = texto.replace('   ', ' ')
    texto = texto.replace('  ', ' ')
    texto = texto.replace(' -', ':\t-')
    return texto
```

- Comenzamos añadiendo espacio tras signo de puntuación. En rigor no está bien, porque lo añadimos *aún si ya había uno*, pero como más adelante sustituiremos las secuencias de dos espacios por uno solo, ese efecto secundario desaparecerá.
- Después cambiamos las secuencias de cuatro espacios por TAB. No es necesario el caso particular de cuatro espacios tras un punto, que tú tenías, pues queda incluido en éste.
- Después cambio secuencias de tres espacios por uno solo.
- Finalmente dos espacios por uno solo
- La última línea no la entiendo, pero estaba en tu código y la he dejado. No sé qué caso intenta cubrir.

El código anterior funcionará razonablemente bien, salvo en casos raros como por ejemplo una secuencia de 7 espacios, que produciría como resultado un TAB y un espacio (porque los 4 primeros se reemplazan por TAB, y luego los 3 siguientes por uno), cuando quizás, el resultado debiera ser un TAB y tres espacios. Pero no esta bien especificado de todas formas qué debe salir en estos casos límite.

## Mayúscula tras punto

Esta parte en cambio no puede hacerse con `replace()`.

Se me ocurre que la forma más simple sería la siguiente. Suponiendo que tras las transformaciones anteriores todas las frases hayan quedado "bien formadas" en el sentido de que tras cada punto aparezca un espacio y solo uno, y después de ese espacio la siguiente palabra (ejemplo: `"Esto va bien. esto es otra frase"`) entonces podemos:

- Dividir todo el texto por los lugares donde aparezca la cadena `". "` (punto y espacio)
- Cada uno de los trozos resultantes será una oración. Pasar a mayúscula la primera palabra de cada una de ellas, usando `string.capitalize()`.
- Volver a juntar todos los trozos en un solo texto, "pegándolos" con la secuencia `". "` entre trozos.

Este código hace eso:

```
oraciones = texto.split(". ")
oraciones_bien = []
for oracion in oraciones:
  oraciones_bien.append(oracion.capitalize())
texto = ". ".join(oraciones_bien)
```

Tiene el efecto secundario de pasar a mayúscula también la primera letra del texto, lo cual me parece correcto por ser el inicio de una oración.

El código se puede escribir de forma mucho más compacta, si habeis dado las *list comprehensions*, así:

```
texto = ". ".join(oracion.capitalize() for oracion in texto.split(". "))
```

Ejemplo:

```
def mayusc_tras_punto(texto):
  texto = ". ".join(oracion.capitalize() for oracion in texto.split(". "))
  return texto

ejemplo = "Esta es una frase. esta es otra. aqui va una tercera. Esta ya estaba bien."
print(mayusc_tras_punto(ejemplo))
```

Sale:

```html
Esta es una frase. Esta es otra. Aqui va una tercera. Esta ya estaba bien.
```

Comment: texto = texto.replace(' -', ':\t-')  ---> se refiere a que si hay un espacio y seguido un guion, que añada dos puntos, salto de linea y guión, pero es \n no \t, me acabo de dar cuenta.

Comment: Pero esta transformación no estaba en tu especificación del problema. Si tienes un enunciado ¿por qué no lo copias en la pregunta?

Comment: La he añadido yo porque el texto que me ha tocado, tiene diálogos

Comment: He probado el codigo de corrección y me sale mal, así que dejo el mío, que me respetaba todo lo que pedía. Peor el tuyo me ha ayudado mogollón a ver el orden. Pero, en el codigo para la mayusculas, me convierte todas las letras tras punto en minúscula.

Comment: @EvaRentero He añadido un ejemplo que muestra que el truco para pasar mayusculas despues del punto funciona correctamente. Puede fallar si el texto de entrada no tiene un punto y _un espacio_ (uno solo) separando oraciones. En ese caso no pasará a mayúscula la primera letra. Pero lo que **nunca** haría sería pasarte otra letra a minúsculas. No me explico cómo puede hacerte eso ¿puedes editar la pregunta y poner el ejemplo completo (código + frase de entrada) en la que te falla?

Comment: Mil gracias! refresqué el entorno y entonces y empezó hacerme caso, errores de principiante. Mil gracias por tu ayuda, arreglo un par de cosas y os cuento.